# How to combine INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN with JPQL and HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to implement an HQL query.  I've been able to implement it in SQL - which I'm a little more familiar with.  What I keep getting hung up on are the INNER JOINS.

The classes are implemented like this...

```
class Item

class Component extends Item
    private Item parentItem;

class Assembly extends Item
```

So far, this is what I have for the HQL...

```
SELECT
item.blah,
comp.blah,
assembly.blah
FROM
Component comp
LEFT OUTER JOIN comp.parentItem item,
Assembly assembly
WHERE 
item.parentItem = assembly
```

This works - except I need for the last three lines to be a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than a mutually exclusive condition.  I've tried to implement this in a number of ways - but I keep running into mapping problems.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class lazy="false" name="com.kcp.common.domain.inventory.Item"
   table="W_INV_INV_ITEM" where="deleted=0">

       <joined-subclass lazy="false" name="com.kcp.common.domain.inventory.Component" table="W_INV_INV_COMPONENT">
         <key>
           <column name="ID">
               <comment>Primary and foreign key to W_INV_INV_ITEM.</comment>
            </column>
         </key>
         <many-to-one cascade="all" class="com.kcp.common.domain.inventory.Item" name="parentItem" outer-join="true">
              <column name="PARENT_ITEM_ID">
                <comment>Foreign key identifying the item to which this component is assembled.</comment>
              </column>
         </many-to-one>
       </joined-subclass>

        <joined-subclass lazy="false" name="com.kcp.common.domain.inventory.Assembly" table="W_INV_INV_MAJOR_ASSEMBLY">   
          <key>
            <column name="ID">
              <comment>Primary and foreign key to W_INV_INV_ITEM.</comment>
            </column>
          </key>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Also - I got it to work in SQL like so...

```
FROM
DBO.W_INV_INV_ITEM item
INNER JOIN DBO.W_INV_INV_COMPONENT comp ON item.id = comp.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.W_INV_INV_ITEM parentInv ON comp.PARENT_ITEM_ID = parentInv.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.W_INV_INV_MAJOR_ASSEMBLY parentMA ON comp.PARENT_ITEM_ID = parentMA.id
```

Answer (score 4):

If you include a LEFT JOIN condition in the WHERE clause, it will act as an INNER JOIN.

If the `item` is optional, then the `item.parentItem` has to be optional too, so you need to include that in a LEFT JOIN.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    i.blah,
    c.blah
FROM Component c
LEFT JOIN c.parentItem i
LEFT JOIN i.parentItem p
WHERE 
    p is null or p.class = 'Assembly'
```

Comment: Getting closer - I still get an SQL.GrammerException error as soon as I add the line LEFT JOIN i.parentItem p. I know that it recognizes the parentItem as a member variable - but it still throws the GrammerException error.

Comment: You need to post your entities.

Comment: I added a summarized version of the hibernate-mapping.  Does that work?